# Unable to get percentage value in SQL Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

Everyone

The below query is working fine without bounce_rate condition. When I am adding the bounce_rate it is throwing an error. Anyone please suggest on this.

```
SELECT
j.emailname, j.emailsubject, s.JobID ,TotalSends ,TotalBounces ,(TotalSends - TotalBounces) AS TotalDelivered, CAST((CAST(TotalBounces AS FLOAT)/CAST(TotalSends AS FLOAT))*100 AS FLOAT) AS Bounce_RATE

FROM

(SELECT
JobID
,MAX(row) as TotalSends
FROM
    (SELECT
    JobID ,row_number()over(partition by JobID order by SubscriberKey ASC) as row
    FROM _Sent ) 

f GROUP BY f.JobID) s

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT
JobID
,MAX(row) as TotalBounces
FROM
    (SELECT
    JobID ,row_number()over(partition by JobID order by SubscriberKey ASC) as row
    FROM _Bounce ) 
d GROUP BY d.JobID) b

ON s.JobID = b.JobID Inner join _job j on s.jobid = j.jobid
```

Answer (score 1):

Marketing Cloud Query Studio doesn't like `CAST` in `SELECT`. You are getting an error there, as it interprets `AS` in `CAST` to be aliasing `AS`. It should work, however, in the Query Activity of Automation Studio.

Regarless, you can make it work in both places by changing `CAST` to `CONVERT`:

```
CONVERT(FLOAT,(CONVERT(FLOAT,TotalBounces)/CONVERT(FLOAT,TotalSends))*100) AS Bounce_RATE
```

Depending on the use case, you might consider using the added power of the `CONVERT` by defining precision and scale:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2),(CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,4),TotalBounces)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,4),TotalSends))*100) AS Bounce_RATE
```

Example output will be 92.45 instead of 92.4482 with the `FLOAT`.

You can check out more about `CAST` vs `CONVERT` and SFMC limitations in [my docs](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-conversion-functions#cast--convert).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say SFMC doesn't like CAST (except Query Studio, which really is not something to rely on for syntax in SFMC) it is just that CONVERT has more options to it and is acceptable in Query Studio. SFMC uses CAST fine in a Query Activity, CONVERT just has better options BUT in some cases, CAST can outperform CONVERT. So its really up to use case as to which is better option. (This has some good insight into performance: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3018/performance-comparison-of-the-sql-server-parse-cast-convert-and-tryparse-trycast-tryconvert-functions/)

Comment: Good point @Gortonington - updated my answer to be more strict.